# Probabilistic algorithm for set cardinality with support deleting from set

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, hyperloglog

Is there any probabilistic algorithm for calculating set cardinality taking into account that must support deleting elements from set? I've been using HyperLogLogs for calculating cardinalities of some sets and their unions but when necessity of deleting elements from set emerged my current solution became unappropriate. Maybe there are some researches or papers related to this topic you could advise.

Comment: Can you explain the problem? What is input and output? Given a finite set, determining its cardinality is usually straight-forward. So I assume, you don't have this set.